# Alternate the renderUI state of TinyMCE editor in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, tinymce

I am trying to alternate the presence of a TinyMCE editor in R Shiny.

I can load the editor, then remove it with the respective `actionButton`s. However, upon attempting to load it more than once, only a `textAreaInput`-type interface is rendered:

```
library(shiny)
library(ShinyEditor)
ui <- fluidPage(
  use_editor("API-KEY"),
     uiOutput("tiny"),
      actionButton("load", "Load TinyMCE"), 
  actionButton( "remove", "Remove TinyMCE" ))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$load, {
 output$tiny = renderUI( editor('textcontent'))})
    observeEvent(input$remove, {
 output$tiny = renderUI( NULL)})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How would it be possible to reload it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try that:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ShinyEditor)

ui <- fluidPage(
  use_editor("API-KEY"),
  uiOutput("tiny"),
  actionButton("btn", "Load/Remove TinyMCE"), 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tiny <- renderUI({
    if(input$btn %% 2 == 0) {
      editor('textcontent')
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And if that doesn't work I would hide it instead of removing it:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ShinyEditor)

ui <- fluidPage(
  use_editor("API-KEY"),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.btn %% 2 == 0",
    uiOutput("tiny")
  ),
  actionButton("btn", "Load/Remove TinyMCE"), 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tiny <- renderUI({
    editor('textcontent')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't get your exact code to perform the desired output. However, your advice to show/hide was the key to finding the solution. I'll add it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following is based on @Stéphane Laurent's advice.

```
library(shiny)
library(ShinyEditor)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  use_editor("API-KEY"),
  useShinyjs(),
  uiOutput("tiny"),
  actionButton( "toggle", "Toggle TinyMCE" ))
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$tiny = renderUI( editor('textcontent'))
  observe({if(input$toggle %% 2 == 0) {
    hide('tiny')
  } else {
    show('tiny')
  }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```